# Rails simple routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a `users_controller`. I've created a `portfolios_controller` which I would like to act similarly to the users_controller; so GETing `/portfolios/10` would actually pull the user with an id of 10. I'm not quite sure how to set up my routes for this. Here's what I have right now in routes.rb:

```
get "portfolios/show"
resources :users
```

I got the following error when trying to access `/portfolios/10`: `The action '10' could not be found for PortfoliosController`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try a `match` statement with an `:id` parameter instead:

```
match "/portfolio/:id" => "portfolios#show"
```

Then you will have access to `params[:id]` in that action.